# Interfacing between ISE and EDK projects

Tags: fpga

I'm doing image processing on fpga (Virtex4). I have written uart program in vhdl and it is working on fpga...its through hyperterminal i'm taking the data...my problem is i want to store my pixels into memory (ddrsdram). I'm going to use EDK for this..
my problem is I have no idea how to interface between my ISE and EDK projects...
I'm new to EDK I cannot understand how to proceed with my EDK
Using ISE and EDK version 11.1

Hoping a quick reply...

Comment: Can you upgrade to 13.1 Webpack (just released)? I think that there have been many improvements over the last few versions in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

First (as you've already heard) upgrade.  Compile times have (IME) got shorter over the last few releases.  And the integration is way improved.

As to your question, you have two options:

- Pull an EDK design into your ISE design - put enough IO pins on the EDK design to talk to your UART design in addition to other IOs.  Have a top level in your ISe which instantiates your EDK design and your UART and wires them up.  And the other EDK IO to the outside world
- Turn your UART design into a pcore, so you can pull it into EDK directly.  Read up on MPD files to start with.

But..... if you're using EDK, what's wrong with their UART?